# Foursquare - How to get menus using file_get_contents from the menu url

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

I can't able to get all the menus from the particular venue id using foursquare API. So I have chosen another method to get the menue details using 'file_get_contents'from the menu url below.

https://foursquare.com/v/mr-teriyaki-burlingame-ca/4b269e61f964a5206f7e24e3/menu

**Code :**

```
$menus  =    file_get_contents("https://foursquare.com/v/mr-teriyaki-burlingame-ca/4b269e61f964a5206f7e24e3/menu");
preg_match_all('/<div class="menu">(.*)<\/div><div>/ims',$menus,$menuDetails);
echo "<pre>";print_r($menuDetails[1][0]);echo "</pre>";
```

Can anyone please give the solution that how to construct the multidimensional array from the menu details like menu name and menu price.

Thanks,

Arularasan D.

Comment: which menu are you targeting anyway? there are like hundreds of it. probably you might want to use `DOMDocument` or `simple-html-dom` instead

Comment: Getting all menus to be an array format.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could use `DOMDocument` with xpath on this:

```
$url = 'https://foursquare.com/v/mr-teriyaki-burlingame-ca/4b269e61f964a5206f7e24e3/menu';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$sections = $xpath->query('//div[@class="section"]'); // get the main section
// this is the div where it holds all the menu's
$menu = array();

// so every/each item inside the menu
foreach($sections as $section) {

    $title = '';
    // first get the title section (Appetizers, etc.)
    $title_node = $xpath->query('.//div[@class="sectionHeader"]/div[@class="contents"]/text()', $section);
    if($title_node->length == 1) { // if this does exist
        $title = $title_node->item(0)->nodeValue; // get the node value  
    } else {
        continue; // else there no reason to linger here, skip
    }

    $items = array();
    // get the 2nd column
    // the name of the food and its price
    $items_node = $xpath->query('.//div[2]/div[@class="entry"]/div[@class="menuHeader"]', $section);
    if($items_node->length > 0) {
        foreach($items_node as $item) {
            if($xpath->query('.//div[@class="price"]', $item)->length > 0) {
                $items[] = array(
                    'title' => $xpath->query('.//span[@class="title"]', $item)->item(0)->nodeValue,
                    'price' => $xpath->query('.//div[@class="price"]', $item)->item(0)->nodeValue,
                );
            }
        }
    }

    // after gathering values in each row (the title and the rows of each item), put the inside an array
    $menu[] = array('title' => $title, 'items' => $items);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($menu);
```

Should print something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [title] => Appetizer‌
        [items] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => Edamame Boiled Soy Beans
                        [price] => 3.95
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => Fried Oyster
                        [price] => 6.95
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => Fried Scallop
                        [price] => 6.95
                    )
```

Comment: Can you please explain that how to troubleshoot each and every line of the code like to print the array $sections = $xpath->query('//div[@class="section"]'); print_r($sections); returns DOMNodeList Object
(
)